# Prevent an accordion from closing when the click happens on the text inside of it

Tags: jquery, accordion

I set up this accordion to listen for clicks on the wrap, but a user should be able to to highlight and copy text from an accordion and so how could I prevent the click event from triggering when the click happens on the text inside of the accordion?

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="accordion-wrap">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <p class="accordion-header"> Accordion header <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-text">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede. </p>
              </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$(".accordion-wrap").on("click", function(event){

    // I have tried with this, but the click is always registered on the wrap:

    if( $(event.target).hasClass("accordion-text") ){
      event.preventDefault;
      return;
    }

      $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
      $(this).children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
      $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header i").removeClass("rotate-fa");
      $(this).find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");
      $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-text").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300);    
});
```

Is there a way of doing this without remaking the whole thing listening for clicks on the accordion-headers instead (which is a possible solution, but I'm interested in knowing if it's possible)?

Example: https://codepen.io/SergiOca/pen/GEdRdX

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.accordion-text', function() {  
return false;
 });
 
 $('body').on('click', '.accordion-wrap', function() {  
 $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
      $(this).children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
      $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header i").removeClass("rotate-fa");
      $(this).find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");
      $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-text").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300);  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <p class="accordion-header"> Accordion header <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-text">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede. </p>
              </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use event delegation and set the event listener to listen on a tag "higher" in hierarchy, with a filter for the specific css class coming from a child element. In this case we have to set one listener for click events coming from `.accordion-text` and prevent them from closing your accordion. We also set the listener for click events coming from an element that contains `.accordion-header` class. I've also improved a bit an event handler function.

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/AndrewKiri/pen/QgrjJL).

Here is the code:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.accordion-text', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
 
$('body').on('click', '.accordion-header', function (event) {
  let accordionWrap = $('.accordion-wrap');
  accordionWrap.children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
  accordionWrap.children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
  accordionWrap.siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
  accordionWrap.siblings().find(".accordion-header i").removeClass("rotate-fa");
  accordionWrap.find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
  accordionWrap.find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");
})
```

Alternatively you can register the `click` handler on `accordion-header` and substitute `$(this)` selector with `accordion-wrap` parent

Here is an [alternative pen](https://codepen.io/AndrewKiri/pen/zzjGLg)

Here is a snipped of code:

```js
$(".accordion-header").on("click", function (event) {
  let accordionWrap = $(event.target.parentElement.parentElement);
  accordionWrap.children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
  accordionWrap.children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
  accordionWrap.siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
  accordionWrap.siblings().find(".accordion-header i").removeClass("rotate-fa");
  accordionWrap.find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
  accordionWrap.find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");
});
```

Comment: The second solution is close, but it's very bugged when tested on an accordion with several items.

Comment: Sergi, I think the best way to achieve this is to copy the functionality from a time-tested source such as bootstrap. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/AndrewKiri/pen/XgywLg). Additional [read](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) about how it works. Now, I'm not propagating to add those libraries, but we can use them to get the insight on how to solve it. So if you're not into adding them into your web-site we can just copy the needed functionality/code. Hope that solves your problem. Please, mark an answer if it has helped you. Thanks

Comment: Why ask a question on SO if you don't plan visiting it, responding to answers or marking an answer at all?